# this keyword from a call back not working with typescript

Tags: typescript, this

```
class Util
{
    callback(callme: () => void)
    {
        callme();
    }
} 


class Greeter {
    greeting: string;
    util: Util;
    Me : Greeter;
    constructor(message: string) {
        this.greeting = message;
        this.util = new Util();
    }
    greet() {
        return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
    }

    callMe()
    {
        this.util.callback(this.greet);         
    }
}

var greeter = new Greeter("world");

var button = document.createElement('button');
button.textContent = "Say Hello";
button.onclick = function() {
    alert(greeter.callMe());
}

document.body.appendChild(button);
```

I am having problems with the this keyword, it is not pointing to the class when I do code like this. How do make this application work? this is pointing to window when used in callback like this...

[link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=class%20Util%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20callback%28callme%3a%20%28%29%20=%3E%20void%29%0A%09%7B%0A%09%09callme%28%29;%0A%09%7D%0A%7D%20%0A%0A%0Aclass%20Greeter%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20greeting%3a%20string;%0A%09util%3a%20Util;%0A%09Me%20%3a%20Greeter;%0A%20%20%20%20constructor%28message%3a%20string%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.greeting%20=%20message;%0A%09%09this.util%20=%20new%20Util%28%29;%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20greet%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22Hello,%20%22%20+%20this.greeting;%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%09%0A%09callMe%28%29%0A%09%7B%0A%09%09this.util.callback%28this.greet%29;%09%09%09%0A%09%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20greeter%20=%20new%20Greeter%28%22world%22%29;%0A%0Avar%20button%20=%20document.createElement%28%27button%27%29;%0Abutton.textContent%20=%20%22Say%20Hello%22;%0Abutton.onclick%20=%20function%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20alert%28greeter.callMe%28%29%29;%0A%7D%0A%0Adocument.body.appendChild%28button%29;%0A)

Comment: You can use a closure if you'd like to capture `this`: `this.util.callback(()=> { this.greet(); });`

Comment: This will help you understand why it happens : https://youtube.com/watch?hd=1&v=tvocUcbCupA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to

```
this.util.callback(this.greet.bind(this));
```

The problem is that when you pass a reference to your greet method, JavaScript just sees a function being passed as argument. When the function is executed it needs a new context and uses whatever "this" represents at that point.

To avoid this, you can bind your function to its context and avoid a new context is assigned to it when executed. To do this, you use `bind`. Its first argument lets you define the context object that should be used when the function is executed.

This would be somewhat equivalent to:

```
var self = this;
this.utils.callback(function(){
   self.greet();
});
```

Which is equivalent to the answer you got on comments using a TypeScript closure

```
() => this.greet();
```

Comment: Thanks Edwin Dalorzo, I like this way of defining a variable to store this